# openGL: gl_instanceID for fragment shader

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

Iv'e written a c++ program that has a number of instances and i want to use glDrawArraysInstanced. is there something similiar to  gl_instanceID for the fragment shader?

Answer (score 7):

just pass it through:

```
varying int instanceID

main(){
    gl_Position = //...
    instanceID = gl_instanceID;
}
```

and use like any other parameter you output from the vertex shader.

Comment: the fragment shader doesn't recognize "int",
or "gl_instanceID"

Comment: that was a part of the vertex shader

Comment: also, seeing as though `gl_InstanceID` is an OpenGL 4 feature, you won't be using `varying` either.